# Running functions on all files in a directory and extracting date from name file

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I wish to extract each csv file in my directory, one at a time, as data frames and perform a sum for each item

For example in Path/data I have the following 4 files:

```
View_Mag_2018_03_01
View_Mag_2018_03_02
View_Mag_2018_03_03
View_Mag_2018_03_04
```

Each file has a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
          place         number
1         chamber1        1
2         chamber2        1 
3         chamber3        2 
4         chamber4        4
5         chamber1        1
6         chamber3        3
```

I would like create 4 data frame (chamber1, chamber2, chamber3, chamber4) with for each data frame the sum by number for the second column and the date extracted from the csv file name for the first column :

Example with chamber1 df:

```
     date        sum
1  O1/03/2018     2
```

Example with chamber2 df:

```
     date        sum
1  O1/03/2018     1
```

And so on for the 4 created data frames and so on with all directory files adding row on these 4 data frames

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried and where do you get stuck? Care to provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first let's reproduce it**

```
df0 <- read.table(text="          place         number
1         chamber1        1
2         chamber2        1 
3         chamber3        2 
4         chamber4        4
5         chamber1        1
6         chamber3        3")

files <- c(
'View_Mag_2018_03_01',
'View_Mag_2018_03_02',
'View_Mag_2018_03_03',
'View_Mag_2018_03_04')

dir.create("Path/data",recursive = TRUE)
sapply(file.path("Path/data",files),write.csv,x=df0)
```

**solution**

we read the data.frames in a list, using the names of the file to add a date column.

```
dfs <- lapply(file.path(path,files),
              function(x) cbind(date=as.Date(substr(x,nchar(x)-9,nchar(x)),format="%Y_%m_%d"),
                                read.csv(x)))
```

Then we rbind all dataframes together

```
big_df <- do.call(rbind,dfs)
```

And aggregate to get our result

```
agg <- aggregate(number ~ date +place,big_df,sum)
#          date    place number
# 1  2018-03-01 chamber1      2
# 2  2018-03-02 chamber1      2
# 3  2018-03-03 chamber1      2
# 4  2018-03-04 chamber1      2
# 5  2018-03-01 chamber2      1
# 6  2018-03-02 chamber2      1
# 7  2018-03-03 chamber2      1
# 8  2018-03-04 chamber2      1
# 9  2018-03-01 chamber3      5
# 10 2018-03-02 chamber3      5
# 11 2018-03-03 chamber3      5
# 12 2018-03-04 chamber3      5
# 13 2018-03-01 chamber4      4
# 14 2018-03-02 chamber4      4
# 15 2018-03-03 chamber4      4
# 16 2018-03-04 chamber4      4
```

Then you can split if desired

```
splitdf <- split(agg,agg$place)
# $chamber1
# date    place number
# 1 2018-03-01 chamber1      2
# 2 2018-03-02 chamber1      2
# 3 2018-03-03 chamber1      2
# 4 2018-03-04 chamber1      2
# 
# $chamber2
# date    place number
# 5 2018-03-01 chamber2      1
# 6 2018-03-02 chamber2      1
# 7 2018-03-03 chamber2      1
# 8 2018-03-04 chamber2      1
# 
# $chamber3
# date    place number
# 9  2018-03-01 chamber3      5
# 10 2018-03-02 chamber3      5
# 11 2018-03-03 chamber3      5
# 12 2018-03-04 chamber3      5
# 
# $chamber4
# date    place number
# 13 2018-03-01 chamber4      4
# 14 2018-03-02 chamber4      4
# 15 2018-03-03 chamber4      4
# 16 2018-03-04 chamber4      4
```

You could get different data.frames using assign with lapply but you probably shouldn't.

**cleanup**

```
unlink(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that's works very good, I have just changed "read.csv" by "read.csv2" to have my plenty header - Secondly files are in XML format from an Excel export in this Directory so How to convert them in a csv format (I had to convert manualy one by one with Excel) ?

Comment: check `xml2::read_xml`, then use `write.csv`. if you have further issues you should ask a new question as its unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
# need the file vector (import with list.files)
files <- c("View_Mag_2018_03_01.csv",
"View_Mag_2018_03_02.csv",
"View_Mag_2018_03_03.csv",
"View_Mag_2018_03_04.csv")
```

than we transform that as dates

```
library(tidyverse)
dates <- files %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  separate(value, c("View", "Mag", "Y", "M", "D"), sep = "_") %>%
  select(Y, M, D) %>%
  unite(date, c("D", "M", "Y")) %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date,"%d_%m_%Y")) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

now we read all files and create a master df

```
df <- NULL
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  df[[i]] <- read_csv(files[i]) %>% select(place, number) %>% 
    group_by(place) %>%
    summarise(sum=sum(number)) %>%
    mutate(date=dates[i,1])
}
result <- bind_rows(df)
```

now we split up into 4 df

```
chamber1 <- result %>% filter(place=="chamber1") %>% select(date, sum)
chamber2 <- result %>% filter(place=="chamber2") %>% select(date, sum)
chamber3 <- result %>% filter(place=="chamber3") %>% select(date, sum)
chamber4 <- result %>% filter(place=="chamber4") %>% select(date, sum)
```

now you have 4 chamber `df`s. 
that should work, let me know.